# Why the heck are my anchor tags still blue?

Tags: html, css

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container {
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

.logo img {
  float: left;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: raleway;
}

#navbar li:hover {
  color: #FFB500;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="" alt="" width="130" />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li> <a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

When I preview the file in chrome, IE and Firefox it looks the way I want it too, Plain black text that changes to orange when hovered over. However when I deploy it to the hosting environment for my school project it ends up just looking blue with the underline and it's ugly. How do I fix this?

Comment: please, indent your code, make it readable, also you can use the rich snippet to make it reproducible, by using the `<>` button while you [edit] your question

Comment: You'd probably look into properly serving the static files at wherever you have the app deployed.

Comment: try putting the styles for "a" at the bottom of the css file. you could also try not using inherit and just moving the styles from the "li" to the "a". and if that doesn't work try using !important on that css rule.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not Reddit, however, and proper language tone is preferred.

Comment: Almost certainly a folder structure path issue..

Answer (score -2):

If you write css in html file, there is no reason that the style didn't work.
So I guess, you separate css and html file ?

Check if you can access the online css file,and is the css being linked to html file correctly.Press F12 in chrome and chenck your css file.

If you couldn't open online css file, your server may have some problem with static file.